# Is there an EDI Segment that can contain more than 256 characters?

Tags: edi, x12

Is there an EDI x12 segment that has no character limit? We often use the MSG segment for open text fields but this is capped at 256 characters, so we’re looking for an alternative that can handle 500+ characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The short answer

The `MTX` Text segment allows you to send messages of up to 4096 characters long, which is the longest available in X12. You can’t just swap out an `MSG` segment for an `MTX` segment, though. You can only use `MTX` if it’s included in the transaction set, and that depends on which X12 'release' (version) you're using.

For [the `005010` release](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-005010/segment/MTX) (one of the more popular ones), here are the transaction sets that `MTX` appears in:

- `105` Business Entity Filings
- `113` Election Campaign and Lobbyist Reporting
- `150` Tax Rate Notification
- `155` Business Credit Report
- `179` Environmental Compliance Reporting
- `194` Grant or Assistance Application
- `251` Pricing Support
- `274` Healthcare Provider Information
- `284` Commercial Vehicle Safety Reports
- `500` Medical Event Reporting
- `620` Excavation Communication
- `625` Well Information
- `650` Maintenance Service Order
- `805` Contract Pricing Proposal
- `806` Project Schedule Reporting
- `814` General Request, Response or Confirmation
- `832` Price/Sales Catalog
- `836` Procurement Notices
- `840` Request for Quotation
- `843` Response to Request for Quotation
- `850` Purchase Order
- `855` Purchase Order Acknowledgment
- `860` Purchase Order Change Request - Buyer Initiated
- `865` Purchase Order Change Acknowledgment/Request - Seller Initiated

## Some additional clarification

- Technically, character limits don't apply to X12 *segments* – what you're referring to is an X12 *element*. A segment is just a container for elements, and the element you're referring to is the element referenced in [MSG01](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-005010/element/933) (the first *element* of the `MSG` *segment*).
- Each X12 element references an ID number. For each element, the ID number points to a dictionary that specifies the name, description, type, minimum length, and maximum length. In the case of `MSG01`, it points to data element `[933][1]`.
- Data element `933` – the one you're currently using – actually has a character limit of 264 characters (more than 256 characters, but not by much). *Note: the link above is to the `005010` X12 release, but I checked backed to `003010` and up to `008030` and it seems to be 264 characters all the way through.*

Now, back to your original question: is there a data element that allows for a larger character payload?

The answer is that there are 8 data elements that accept a payload larger than 264 characters.

Two of them are binary data types, which we can likely eliminate off the bat:

- [785](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-005010/element/785). **Binary Data**. A string of octets which can assume any binary pattern from hexadecimal 00 to FF. Note: The maximum length is dependent upon the maximum data value that can be entered in DE 784, which value is 999,999,999,999,999. *Max characters: 999999999999999.*
- [1700](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-005010/element/1700). **Transformed Data**. Binary or filtered data having one or more security policy options applied; transformed data may represent compressed, encrypted, or compressed and encrypted plaintext. *Max characters: 10000000000000000.*

The rest are strings, which is promising:

- [364](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-005010/element/364). **Communication Number**. Complete communications number including country or area code when applicable. *Max characters: 2048.*
- [1565](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-005010/element/1565).  **Look-up Value**. Value used to identify a certificate containing a public key. Max characters: 4096.
- [1566](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-005010/element/1566). **Keying Material**. Additional material required for decrypting the one-time key. *Max characters: 512.*
- [1567](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-005010/element/1567). **One-time Encryption Key**. Hexadecimally filtered encrypted one-time key. *Max characters: 512.*
- [1573](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-005010/element/1573). **Encoded Security Value.** Encoded representation of the Security Value specified by the Security Value Qualifier. *Max characters: 1.00E+16.*

And, last but not least:

- [1551](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-005010/element/1551). **Textual Data**. To transmit large volumes of message text. *Max characters: 4096.*

Looks like a winner!

Note that element 1551 appears in only one segment: [MTX](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-005010/segment/MTX), which was introduced [in the `003060` X12 release](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-003060/segment/MTX). And in the initial `003060` release, it was only included in one X12 Transaction Set: `194 Grant or Assistance Application` (which makes sense – a longer field was needed for grant applications).

It seems that as new releases were developed, the `MTX` segment made its way into more and more transaction sets – likely for exactly the reason you're asking. [In `003070`](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-003070/segment/MTX), it was included in 5 transaction sets; [in `004010`](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-004010/segment/MTX), 15; [in `005010`](https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-005010/segment/MTX), 24, and so on.

The `MTX` segment uses element `1551` in both `MTX02` and `MTX03`, so you can get double the length by using both of them. Note that there's a 'relational condition': `If MTX-03 is present, then MTX-02 is required` (in other words, you can't use `MTX03` if you don't use `MTX02` first).

And depending on the transaction set, the `MTX` segment may be able to be repeated as well.

Long story short: if the `MTX` segment is in the transaction set / release you're using, you're likely in luck.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple MSGs and trim the data at each to the maximum allowed. You usually have free text segments set with repetitions > 1, so you should be okay. That's how everybody does it.

Comment: I agree this is probably the most common solution I’ve come across, but our system doesn’t support splitting a single message across multiple segments. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Wow, I feel you. What system are you using?

Comment: We built our own system, none of us had prior EDI experience, so we figured most of the major aspects on the fly out but some of the more subtle aspects like element character limits slipped by.

Comment: Are you saying the cap on the MSG segment is imposed by the system you built in-house? If yes, then what is stopping you to remove this limitation?

Comment: No, our system does not impose the limitation, we can place how ever many characters we want. We are running into issues when we integrate with our suppliers. Some cannot process our documents because some fields violate the character constraints.

Comment: In that case, it's your suppliers that you need to agree on how to pass data across. Obviously, their system is more EDI-aware, and they'll be able to guide you on how to pass on free text. Note that suppliers usually have established maps and aren't particularly open to changing them, especially on something as trivial as free text.